# How to map sales team to all my contact

Tags: contacts

Happy Evening !

CiviCRM in Drupal 7 - XAMPP

1) I was trying to connect each contact into a other contact(Sales Team) and to create a relationship as "(Contact of Sales Person 1)".

2) Created a even registration - I want to display sale(s) person contact and in a field called "Company contact" and all these sales person will be listed in the registration form itself...

Any help would be great full

Comment: There won't be any way to do this out of the box in civicrm. You are more likely to be able to get all the contacts related to Contact 1 via a Webform-civicrm approach since you can set it up to include many contacts and if contact 1 is logged in then their related contacts could be loaded. webform_civicrm is very well documented so i would suggest you read, try and come back with more detailed questions

Comment: decided to add above as answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand the intention here, ie John has relationship to Mary, Bob, Harry, then on an Event registration page automatically fill the form with Mary and/or Bob and/or Harry (as well as John or not?).

There won't be any way to do this out of the box in civicrm afaik. Since you are on Drupal you are more likely to be able to get close.

John can go to a form and use an autocomplete/dropdown to find contacts he has 'permission' to see, which you can provide by making your Relationship between John and the others Permissioned (see this [Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) if you want to make those types of relationships always permissions)

You can then set up the webform to allow John to add multiple of his sales team, or probably have them all load automatically

And yes the Webform-civicrm can be used to add these contacts to an Event, and accept payment depending on the type of payment processor you use.

[Webform_civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) is very well documented so i would suggest you read, try and come back with more detailed questions